# Error Serverless: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, serverless, aws-serverless

when executing the command: `serverless deploy`, I get the following error

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying my-project to stage dev (us-east-1)
Optimize: starting engines
Optimize: my-project-dev-main

× Stack onfield-api-v3-dev failed to deploy (12s)
Environment: win32, node 16.10.0, framework 3.30.1 (local) 3.30.1v (global), plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

The walkthrough of configuration options in .eslintrc.js, serverless.yml and browserify
I have only obtained more errors and dead ends

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I can only recommend to add `console.log()` with error to `serverless-optimize` plugin inside `node_module` directly. Here you should see something like this:

```
node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist/index.js:1\n' +
    "import { EventEmitter } from 'events';\n" +
    '^\n' +
    "ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'",
```

Then simply add the package that makes an issue for you to **optimize** **external** object in **serverless** config.